# box-shadow with :before and :after [CSS3]

Tags: asp.net, html, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to create the following effect in my current project:

http://jsfiddle.net/pns2050/7TYTc/2/

But when i try to add it to my website the 2 bottom corners lose that angle effect..

my website consists of a Masterpage which basicly creates a table in the middle for the content to be added..

```
<div class="clearboth"></div>
<div id="pageWrap">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div><!--/Page Wrap-->
```

with CSS

```
#pageWrap
{
width:950px;
height:700px;
margin:-30px auto -20px auto;
box-shadow: -1px -5px 20px 5px #80b840;
background-color:white;
position:relative;   
}
```

so i add in my default.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" 
 Runat="Server"> 
  <div class="box effect2">
    <h3>Effect 2</h3>
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```

with the CSS shown in jsfiddle but the effect breaks..

I know my question is vague but i tried everything and i cant see where the problem is..I could recreate this in some older projects of mine..

I am just looking for a little hint/idea from someone experienced to give me strength so i  can keep trying ;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because of `z-index: -1;` set on the pseudoelements, while `#pageWrap` has `z-index:0` (default) and `background-color:white;` which is covering the shadow.

You can solve it adding:

```
#pageWrap {
z-index:-2;
/* etc */
```

or removing the white background.

Comment: Anyway to do this keeping the background?